# Bash vlookup kind of solution

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I have two files, 
File 1

```
2,1,1,1,Test1,1540584051,52
6,5,1,1,Test2,1540579206,54
3,3,0,0,Test3,1540591243,36
```

File 2

```
2,1,0,2,Test1,1540584051,52
6,5,0,2,Test2,1540579206,54
```

i want to look up column 7 value from File 1 to check if it matches with column 7 value from File 2 and when matched, replace the that line in file 2 with corresponding line in file 1
So the output would be

```
2,1,1,1,Test1,1540584051,52
6,5,1,1,Test2,1540579206,54
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that with the following script:

```
BEGIN { FS="," }

NR==FNR {
    lookup[$7] = $0
    next
}

{
    if (lookup[$7] != "") {
        $0 = lookup[$7]
    }
    print
}

END {
    print ""
    print "Lookup table used was:"
    for (i in lookup) {
        print "   Key '"i"', Value '"lookup[i]"'"
    }
}
```

The `BEGIN` section simply sets the field separator to `,` so individual fields can be easily processed.

The `NR` and `FNR` variables are, respectively, the line number of the *full* input stream (all files) and the line number of the *current* file in the input stream. When you are processing the first (or only) file, these will be equal, so we use this as a means to simply *store* the lines from the first file, keyed on field seven.

When `NR` and `FNR` are *not* equal, it's because you've started the second file and this is where we want to replace lines if their key exists in the first file.

This is done by simply checking if a line exists in the lookup table with the desired key and, if it does, replacing the current line the lookup table line. Then we print the (original or replaced) line.

The `END` section is there just for debugging purposes, it outputs the lookup table that was created and used, and you can remove it once you're satisfied the script works as expected.

---

You'll see the output in the following transcript, illustrating hopefully that it *is* working correctly:

```
pax$ cat file1
2,1,1,1,Test1,1540584051,52
6,5,1,1,Test2,1540579206,54
3,3,0,0,Test3,1540591243,36

pax$ cat file2
2,1,0,2,Test1,1540584051,52
6,5,0,2,Test2,1540579206,54

pax$ awk -f sudarshan.awk file1 file2
2,1,1,1,Test1,1540584051,52
6,5,1,1,Test2,1540579206,54

Lookup table used was:
   Key '36', Value '3,3,0,0,Test3,1540591243,36'
   Key '52', Value '2,1,1,1,Test1,1540584051,52'
   Key '54', Value '6,5,1,1,Test2,1540579206,54'
```

---

If you need it as a "short as possible" one-liner to use from your script, just use:

```
awk -F, 'NR==FNR{x[$7]=$0;next}{if(x[$7]!=""){$0=x[$7]};print}' file1 file2
```

though I prefer the readable version myself.

Comment: Thanks for amazing explanation

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r 's|^([^,]*,){6}([^,]*).*|/^([^,]*,){6}\2/s/.*/&/p|' file1 | sed -rnf - file2
```

Turn file1 into a sed script and using the 7th field as a key lookup replace any line in file2 that matches.

In your example the 7th field is the last one, so a short version of the above solution is:

```
sed -r 's|.*,(.*)|/.*,\1/s/.*/&/p|' file1 | sed -nf - file2
```

Comment: Hi Your answer is also correct and solve the issue but it allows only one answer to be correct.. But thanks for quick response...